# PivotTable - sort by sum of specific columns

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have a certain problem with sorting my pivot table.
I need to sort it by the sum of values from specific columns.
I want to sort "Marka Główna" by the sum of months for Year2, it looks like on the screen below, selected columns are the ones which make the sum I need to sort by.

Here is the screen shot:

[image: img]

Is this doable? I cannot have subtotals for each year visible in the table, can it be done with sorting by subtotal in that situation?

Comment: I can't test on your data but I think if you right click the pivot > Pivot Table Options >  Totals and Filters tab > `Allow multiple filter per field` ... then you could filter or group it differently.  See also [Group or Ungroup Data in a Pivot Table](https://support.office.com/article/group-or-ungroup-data-in-a-pivottable-c9d1ddd0-6580-47d1-82bc-c84a5a340725). I assume you've played with the subtotals in Field Options.  If the months are static, maybe you could add them with a calculated field.

Comment: Hey @ashleedawg, thanks for the comment. The problem is that the table stores large amount of data, thus calculated fields always crash excel file and I can't use them, I used `Allow multiple filter per field` you mentioned and grouped the months into by years and got something like this:
[link](https://imgur.com/a/KVLlKhc)
Now I can sort by the field sum Y2, but I can't have those visible here in the table, as from what I read you can't move the subtotals to the end of the table, and this is where i need to have them. Maybe you know if there is a way to sort by fields that aren't visible?

Comment: @ashleedawg First thing I thought of is just hiding those columns, but I would really prefer if they were not in the table at all.